# JQuery - Как сделать, чтобы mmenu выезжало сверху над контентом, а контент не сдвигался?

Tags: jquery, menu, mobile

Как сделать так, чтобы `mmenu` выезжало сверху над контентом, а контент оставался бы на месте, то есть не сдвигался?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код свой добавь...

Comment: А че не нравится-то, Evgen? вроде нормально выглядит сайт. Я б так и оставил.